# How to correctly iterate over all BigQuery result rows?

Tags: java, google-api, google-bigquery

I'm selecting one column from a BigQuery table like

```
select url from `project.dataset.urllist` where status = 2
```

A count(*) gives me 245217 results and I can query this number of rows in the
browser console.

Implementing the same in Java according to the example on
https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api looks like

```
QueryResponse response = bigquery.query(queryRequest);
QueryResult result = response.getResult();

while (result != null) {
  for (List<FieldValue> row : result.iterateAll()) {
    ... do something
  }
  result = result.getNextPage();
}
```

However I end up with 435651 result rows returned from 3 QueryResult pages.

I found out that in the first iteration of the while-loop I already get
the desired 245217 rows; the second and third iteration return a part
of the same results again.
Without the while-loop I receive what I expect, but is that correct?

```
QueryResult result = response.getResult();
for (List<FieldValue> row : result.iterateAll()) {
  ... do something
}
```

Apparently, first result page contain all rows from #1 to #245217,
the second page contains rows from #100000 to #245217,
the third page contains rows from #200000 to #245217.
Is that a Bug in the API?

Comment: Strange language in the [Javadoc](http://googlecloudplatform.github.io/google-cloud-java/0.9.3/apidocs/com/google/cloud/PageImpl.html#iterateAll--) for `QueryResult`: `Returns an iterator for all values, possibly also in the next pages`

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From practical point of view, the short answer on how to correctly iterate over all BigQuery rows seems to be:

- just rely on `QueryResult#iterateAll()` in the current version of Google Cloud Java Client Core (1.4.0) and BigQuery (0.22.0-beta); and remove that outer loop through result pages.

---

#### Consideration

Let's take a look into the implementation of `iterateAll` method which is inherited by `QueryResult` from `com.google.cloud.PageImpl`. Currently, this method returns an Iterator which starts from current page and seems to fetch next page once all elements of the current page have been iterated ([github link](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/blob/815f4370223332fbb32d0e4dedbb521dbebfc72f/google-cloud-core/src/main/java/com/google/cloud/PageImpl.java#L53)). This happens upon corresponding `computeNext()` call, where `currentPage = currentPage.getNextPage();` explicitly occurs

That is, `result.getNextPage().iterateAll()` returns Iterator which start over iterating elements from the first element of page returned by `getNextPage` and will iterate over the all next pages until reached last element of the last page. The only difference to `result.iterateAll()` is that last one returns Iterator started from the very first page.

In the light of above, wrapping `result.iterateAll()` call into additional loop through the pages is redundant, so looks like [current version of example](https://cloud.google.com/bigquery/create-simple-app-api) is not 100% consistent and requires removal of that surrounding loop

```
while (result != null) {
  ...
  result = result.getNextPage();
}
```

In terms of consistency of the API itself - there is a lack of clear way of handling results on a per-page basis as we neither have alternative to `iterateAll` for particular rows on a particular page, nor have ability to clearly identify that end of current page is reached (except ability to manually count the rows while iterating). But still, when working with the entire result through all rows - this seems not to be a blocker

### Edit

Please note that [Java Client for BigQuery](https://github.com/GoogleCloudPlatform/google-cloud-java/tree/master/google-cloud-bigquery) is in beta for the moment of writing, and there is clearly stated:

> Note: This client is a work-in-progress, and may occasionally make backwards-incompatible changes.

That means we should expect further changes and adjust the approach of working through all rows accordingly.